# AlarmManager or Handler

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-handler, android-tv

I have specific case to ping my server **every 10-60 minutes** (it still depends) but only when app is opened.
This feature is created to inform that session is still open where session is defined as period from app open to app close. I don't have to worry about process kill.

What is **better to use**? **AlarmManager** or **Handler**.postDelayed() ?

The targeted platform is android tv so imagine the case is when watching film in context of my app for example.

Personally I first thought to use AlarmManager but I realized it's way more code to produce compared the circumstances.
Is handler causing more **CPU** usage **increase** ?

Comment: `Is handler causing more CPU usage increase ?` no of course since you are only pinging ever 10- 60mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AlarmManager` starts your app in the future when it is not running. So I think `Handler.postDelayed()` is a more efficient choice if you will only ping the server when the app is open.

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

See [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use `AlarmManager` for this use case. I can think of several reasons right away:

1. If you use `Handler` and want to post a "cancellable" `Runnable` to it, then you'll have to store references to both the `Handler` and the `Runnable` in order to be able to cancel the execution (e.g. if user leaves your app). It means that you'll have to either store them in an `Application` context, or create a `Service` for this feature. Using `Application` for this kind of stuff is generally discouraged, and `Service` is a bit of an overkill.
2. `AlarmManager` is the standard API for this kind of stuff. Any other developer reading your source code (or yourself in few months) will have a much easier time understanding the feature.
3. I don't see how you can have less code using `Handler` approach - all you need in order to use `AlarmManager` is a single method that creates `PendingIntent`, which is being passed to both `set` and `cancel` methods in `AlarmManager`...
4. As for CPU usage, I'm sure that the scale will be insignificant, therefore it won't matter.

In general, I think that `Handler#postDelayed` should not be used to control flows that involve user interactions. It just feels wrong and clumsy.

Comment: ad 3) of course Handker solution is way easier,  no need for PendingIntent,  no custom broadcast etc,  ad 4) not at all, see MessageQueue.java sources

Comment: @pskink, 3) since OP wants to communicate with a server, I assumed that he already has `Service` that takes care of networking. In this case no need for `BroadcastRceiver`. If it is not the case, and all network requests are "inlined" in `Activities` and `Fragments` (using e.g. `AsyncTask`), then my answer might not apply. 4) can you elaborate?

Comment: see how `Looper#loop` works [here](http://androidxref.com/2.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#106) and the `next` method is [here](http://androidxref.com/2.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java#91), it is really quite efficient

Comment: @pskink, yes, I know. You may be referring to the original answer (before edition) - I thought that OP is referring to posting to a new `Thread` (e.g. `HandlerThread`), but then I realized that he refers to UI thread. In any case, I think that in the described scenario energy differences will be negligible.

Comment: @pskink, what do you think about 1? Are you comfortable with keeping a reference to `Runnable` for app's lifetime? Feels wrong to me.

Comment: `HandlerThread` uses `Looper` as well, it is 2 in 1: a `Thread` + `Looper` combo

Comment: i think OP means `Activity` (`only when app is opened`) so storing them in `Activity` would be a "normal thing", see [Filter.java](http://androidxref.com/2.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/Filter.java) for example on how they are filtering things using `HandlerThread`

Comment: @pskink, looks like we have quite different point of views on the problem itself, therefore let's wrap up and let OP choose what suits him.

Comment: yes we have, but did you notice `AlarmManager` docs saying: `Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.` ?

Comment: @yes I did, but as I said, I don't like the idea of storing a reference to `Runnable` and it feels awkward to use `Handler` in a flow involving user interaction. `AlarmManager` approach makes use of just static constants and does not add complexity (given there is a `Service` that can be reused). It will also be easier to test.

Comment: i see your point,  when it comes to Handlers i never use Runnables as they only make the code clumsy, slower and bigger,  i am hard core geek who uses raw Messages,  thats the fun!

Comment: it's going to start from application context not any particular view. Storing runnable isn't that wrong, and compared to setting pending intent and broadcasts receiver which I don't have (service as well) is easier. If that doesn't influence performance (I thought that under Handler.postDelay is has to be taken it into account in every UI loop iteration) then I use Handler. Thx !

Comment: Is using messages comes with: Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed() ?

Comment: @AdamStyrc when using `Message`s you can use any `send*` method, so you have 7 methods you can use (warning: `sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue` is evil though)

Comment: @AdamStyrc but of course if you want "delayed" execution use `sendEmptyMessageDelayed` or `sendEmptyMessageAtTime` or `sendMessageDelayed` or `sendMessageAtTime`