# which one is best AlarmManager or Handler post delay for repeating background task

Tags: android, alarmmanager, handler

I have to repeat a weather API Task after every half an hour to fetch data from the http://api.openweathermap.org for that I have used handler post delay but some one suggests me to use Alarm manager for repeating task as It produces interrupt. but if we use handler it consume more memory and uses more Cpu. I need suggestion which one is best.

Comment: Voting to close: This is a matter of opinion

Comment: @LunarWatcher I m sorry about that, for a suggestion where should I post, and someone voting down my question.

Comment: @LunarWatcher ok, but please neutral it.

Comment: @LunarWatcher this question is a _very_ poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat I checked the tour again, I saw `software development methods and practices` and assumed it was fine (the first time). I see the part where it says that recommending tools and such is off-topic now.

Comment: @gnat please tell me where it should be??

Comment: @gnat now I have to delete it?? because votes are going down due to off-topic.

Comment: @gnat this Question is same as me but no says that it's off-topic.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159127/alarmmanager-or-handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) point it out when to use it.

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

In your case your app will not be visible all the time since it's a weather app. It makes sense to use `AlarmManager` here to update the data. For more pro's and con's there are more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=alarmmanager+or+handler)

It's always case dependent.

Answer (score -1):

Previously SyncAdapters were used for performing long performing operations, Now JobSchedular is the latest background monitoring service which can be used.